# Add constructor logic here

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to finish this piece of code so my smtp web.config code will send an email. I never made this code so I am unsure of what has to go at the top. I'm very new to coding and have never done web development before getting the job I have now. Right after `public EmailHelper()` in comments it says `To Do: Add constructor logic here.` I don't understand what the person who wrote it means.

Note: I took out the email and passwords so you could not see them they were not left out by accident.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using IBEW2330_2018.Domain;

    namespace IBEW2330_2018.Helpers
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Summary description for EmailService
        /// </summary>
        public class EmailHelper
        {
            public EmailHelper()
            {
                //
                // TODO: Add constructor logic here
                //

            }
            public static string SendEmailWithCCList(string emailBody, string Subject, string emailTo, List<Member> member) //TODO: Edit/Test
            {
                string message = "";
                try
                {
                    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                    mail.To.Add(emailTo);

                    if (member != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Member m in member)
                        {
                            if(Validator.EmailIsValid(m.EmailAddress))
                            {
                                mail.Bcc.Add(m.EmailAddress);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("", Subject, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    mail.Subject = Subject;
                    mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    mail.Body = emailBody;
                    mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                    client.Port = 2525;
                    client.Host = "port80.smtpcorp.com";
                    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Send(mail);
                    message = "alert('Successfully Sent...');";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Exception ex2 = ex;
                    string errorMessage = string.Empty;
                    while (ex2 != null)
                    {
                        errorMessage += ex2.ToString();
                        ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
                    }
                    message = "alert('Sending Failed...');";
                }
                return message;
            }

            public static string SendEmailWithFrom(string emailBody, string Subject, string emailTo, string ccEmailTo, string emailFrom) //TODO: Edit/Test
            {
                string message = "";
                try
                {
                    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                    mail.To.Add(emailTo);
                    if (ccEmailTo != "")
                    {
                        mail.CC.Add(ccEmailTo);
                    }
                    mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom, Subject, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    mail.Subject = Subject;
                    mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    mail.Body = emailBody;
                    mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

                    //TODO: Comment out
                    client.Port = 2525;
                    client.Host = "port80.smtpcorp.com";
                    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Send(mail);
                    message = "alert('Successfully Sent...');";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Exception ex2 = ex;
                    string errorMessage = string.Empty;
                    while (ex2 != null)
                    {
                        errorMessage += ex2.ToString();
                        ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
                    }
                    message = "alert('Sending Failed...');";
                }
                return message;
            }


            public static string SendEmail(string emailBody, string Subject, string emailTo, string ccEmailTo) //TODO: Edit/Test
            {
                string message = "";
                try
                {
                    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                    mail.To.Add(emailTo);
                    if (ccEmailTo != "")
                    {
                        mail.CC.Add(ccEmailTo);
                    }
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("", Subject, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    mail.Subject = Subject;
                    mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    mail.Body = emailBody;
                    mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                    //mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Code/ChristmasParty.pdf")));
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                    client.Port = 2525;
                    client.Host = "port80.smtpcorp.com";
                    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Send(mail);
                    message = "alert('Successfully Sent...');";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Exception ex2 = ex;
                    string errorMessage = string.Empty;
                    while (ex2 != null)
                    {
                        errorMessage += ex2.ToString();
                        ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
                    }
                    message="alert('Sending Failed...');";
                }
                return message;
            }

            public static string SendEmailWithAttachments(string emailBody, string Subject, string emailTo, string ccEmailTo, ArrayList strAttach) //TODO: Edit/Test
            {
                string message = "";
                try
                {
                    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                    //mail.To.Add(emailTo);
                    mail.To.Add("");
                    if (ccEmailTo != "")
                    {
                        mail.CC.Add(ccEmailTo);
                    }
                    /*live on cartika*/
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("mailer@smtp.ibew.nf.ca", Subject, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    //mail.From = new MailAddress("diane@ibew.nf.ca", Subject, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    mail.Subject = Subject;
                    mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    mail.Body = emailBody;
                    mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                    int i=0;
                    for (i = 0; i <=  strAttach.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/usr/pdf/certs/" + strAttach[i].ToString())));
                    }
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                    client.Port = 587;
                    client.Host = "mail.smtp.ibew.nf.ca";
                    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
                    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
                    client.EnableSsl = false;
                    client.Send(mail);
                    client.Port = 2525;
                    client.Host = "port80.smtpcorp.com";
                    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Send(mail);
                    message = "alert('Successfully Sent...');";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Exception ex2 = ex;
                    string errorMessage = string.Empty;
                    while (ex2 != null)
                    {
                        errorMessage += ex2.ToString();
                        ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
                    }
                    message = "alert('Sending Failed...');";
                }
                return message;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For your information, SmtpClient is deprecated by Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8 They recommend the use of MailKit instead.

Comment: Can you ask the person who wrote it? Does it compile anyway? My attitudes to comments is to ignore them

Comment: That comment is auto-generated by Visual Studio. Do not worry about that unless you have to.

Comment: The person who wrote it is no longer an employee. It does compile but no email gets sent out. I tried to contact the person as well but did not receive a reply.

Comment: This question cannot be answered, as we don't know who left the code like that.  Regardless, it seems like the question you *really* want to ask is 'why is this not working'. I'd suggest closing this and asking a new question, with a  [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

Just ignore it. It is apparently an auto-generated comment to guide you where to write your constructor. So you can just remove it and you will be fine, and also you will be saving a couple of bytes ;).